# How to make output visible while running the code from VS?

Tags: visual-studio, logging, window, trace

I can see the output window with logging information only when I stop/exit the application. How to make it  visible while running the code from VS?

Comment: Is the output windows set to auto hide?

Comment: @Ashwini no, docked as tabbed document(so I can always see it when writting code :D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Output window before or while running the application (*View -> Output* or *ALT+2*).

Comment: Alt+2 doesnt work, but when I select it from menu it works :)